# ¿Error al enviar form atravez de ajax, PHP, (servidor apache corriendo en ubuntu server)?

Tags: php, ajax

mi proyecto los corria en XAMPP,
y ahi iban perfecto.

pero luego los pase a un ubuntu server,
para correrlos desde ayi,
ahora recibo los siguientes errores al intentar hacer un envio de form usando ajax.
las consultas SELECT me funciona correctamnete con ajax pero aparentemente estoy teniendo problemas con las otras consultas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no se si debo hacer alguna configuracion extra en el servidor apache ubuntu, o en php,
agradezco sus respuestas.

Comment: Puedes poner el mensaje completo de error?, parece que dice que peso_llego_kg_mp no tiene un valor por defecto, es decir, no lo está intentando grabar, revisa que lo estas enviando o pon nullable la columna, cuando cambias de windows a linux regularmente los problemas vienen con las mayúsculas y minúsculas, en linux las diferencías y en windows no, puede que por ahí vaya el asunto.

Comment: eso es lo que no entiendo porque ese campo no lo estoy enviando

Comment: entonces intenta poner "nullable" ese campo, es decir que permita valores vacíos porque es el error que está enviando el servidor.

Comment: pana muchas gracias. aunque no los estoy enviando en el INSERT, es correcto que deben estar permitidos como NULL, lo que quiero saber es porque sucede esto? ya que en xampp esto no pasaba

Comment: Debe ser la forma en que se creó la tabla, por default debería ser null, a menos que en engine no lo permita, como dice en el link, "En MySQL 8.0, solo los motores de almacenamiento InnoDB, MyISAM y MEMORY admiten índices en columnas que pueden tener valores NULL. En otros casos, debe declarar las columnas indexadas como NOT NULL o se producirá un error. " https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html  es posible que el engine por defecto es diferente al que estabas utilizando o sí hubo un cambio explícito en el script de creación de la base de datos.